# How can a Jinja template handle versions comparison in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a file that has all the environments release versions, `release_versions`:

```yaml
prod: 10.7.2

dev1: 10.8
dev2: 10.7
dev3: 10.6.2
dev4: 10.7.2
dev5: 10.7.1
```

I need, in Ansible, to have a template Jinja comparing those versions to the production release version, and tells me which environments need to be updated and which does not, like this:

```
dev1: 10.8
dev2: 10.7(need to update to 10.7.2)
dev3: 10.6.2(need to update to 10.7.2)
dev4: 10.7.2
dev5: 10.7.1(need to update to 10.7.2)
```

Since the version can have 3 numbers separate by a dot (`.`), I cannot use a float format.

Here is my code:

```yaml
prod_db_version: "10.7.2"

- copy:
    dest: /tmp/version.txt
    content: |
    {% for i in release_versions %}
    {{ i.name }}: {{ i.version }}{% if format(j.version|float) < format(prod_db_version|float) %}(need to update to {{prod_db_version}}){% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This works if all the versions have only two numbers (e.g.: `10.7`).

How can I make this work with versions like `10.7.2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`version` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/version_test.html) added to Jinja by Ansible for this kind of use case:

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      {%
        for version in release_versions | dict2items
        if version.key != 'prod'
      %}
        {{ version.key }}: {{ version.value }} {%
          if version.value is version(release_versions.prod, '<')
        %}(need to update to {{ release_versions.prod }}){% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
  vars:
    release_versions:
      prod: 10.7.2
      dev1: 10.8
      dev2: 10.7
      dev3: 10.6.2
      dev4: 10.7.2
      dev5: 10.7.1
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |2-
      dev1: 10.8
      dev2: 10.7 (need to update to 10.7.2)
      dev3: 10.6.2 (need to update to 10.7.2)
      dev4: 10.7.2
      dev5: 10.7.1 (need to update to 10.7.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat release_versions.yml
prod: 10.7.2

dev1: 10.8
dev2: 10.7
dev3: 10.6.2
dev4: 10.7.2
dev5: 10.7.1
```

Read the file and put it into a dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: release_versions.yml
        name: release_versions
```

Declare the variables

```yaml
  prod: "{{ release_versions.prod }}"
  updt: "{{ release_versions|dict2items|
            selectattr('key', 'match', 'dev')|
            selectattr('value', 'version', '10.7', '<=')|
            items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  prod: 10.7.2

  updt:
    dev2: 10.7
    dev3: 10.6.2
    dev5: 10.7.1
```

Write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/version.txt
        content: |
          {{ updt|to_nice_yaml }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/version.txt 
dev2: 10.7
dev3: 10.6.2
dev5: 10.7.1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    prod: "{{ release_versions.prod }}"
    updt: "{{ release_versions|dict2items|
              selectattr('key', 'match', 'dev')|
              selectattr('value', 'version', prod, '<')|
              items2dict }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: release_versions.yml
        name: release_versions

    - debug:
        var: prod
    - debug:
        var: updt

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/version.txt
        content: |
          {{ updt|to_nice_yaml }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare the versions with multiple numbers separated by ".", you can split the version strings into separate numbers and then compare them one by one. Here's an updated Ansible Jinja code that should work for comparing versions with 3 numbers:

```
prod_db_version: "10.7.2"

- copy:
    dest: /tmp/version.txt
    content: |
      {% for i in release_versions %}
      {% set ver_nums = i.version.split('.') %}
      {% set prod_nums = prod_db_version.split('.') %}
      {% set num_len = max(ver_nums|length, prod_nums|length) %}
      {% set need_update = false %}
      {% for j in range(num_len) %}
        {% set ver_num = ver_nums[j]|default(0)|int %}
        {% set prod_num = prod_nums[j]|default(0)|int %}
        {% if ver_num < prod_num %}
          {% set need_update = true %}
          {% break %}
        {% elif ver_num > prod_num %}
          {% break %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {{ i.name }}: {{ i.version }}{% if need_update %}(need to update to {{prod_db_version}}){% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

This code splits both the production version and the environment version into separate numbers using the split method. It then loops through the numbers and compares them one by one using an inner for loop. If it finds a number in the environment version that is less than the corresponding number in the production version, it sets the need_update variable to true and breaks out of the loop. Otherwise, if it finds a number in the environment version that is greater than the corresponding number in the production version, it breaks out of the loop without setting need_update to true. If the need_update variable is true after the loop, it prints the environment name and version with a message indicating that it needs to be updated to the production version.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this approach a try!